# Remove tag synonym [sequel] -> [sql]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

The [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) database ORM for Ruby is perhaps unfortunately named, and happens to generate [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL), but it is quite distinct.

There may be some users who have incorrectly used [sequel](/questions/tagged/sequel) when they meant [sql](/questions/tagged/sql), but there have also historically been plenty of correct taggings using [sequel](/questions/tagged/sequel). With the approval of this synonym, data has been lost.

I used to browse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sequel and see a list of reasonable questions about the library. Now I get a flood of information n00b questions. Any questions that were (as fashion has it) only tagged [sequel](/questions/tagged/sequel), but didn't use that word in the title or question, are now quite confusing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah .. very poor action by the community .. deleted the synonym  ... what more now there are no questions tagged sequel to be found.

We really need an undo option, its possible we could find these through post history

Comment: My bad, I approved that synonym yesterday.  There were only about 40 tagged 'sequel' so I thought it was a mistake.

Comment: If you care to manually restore them, probably most/all of the [answers by jeremyevans](http://stackoverflow.com/users/132053/jeremy-evans#qpage_1-apage_1-qsort_votes-asort_votes) were related to Sequel. I'm also happy to do this, but want to wait to see if you mods have a more automated mechanism than just opening/editing/saving each.

Comment: @Phrogz: Great idea!  Between that, a Google search, and a look through all the questions tagged both `[ruby]` and `[sql]`, I think I got them all restored (plus a few extras).  Sorry about the mix up.

Comment: Someone should probably do a sequel tag wiki to explain what it is.