# Need a rollback/undo for tag synonym merging

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, undelete, undo

Per [waffles' response to my recent support request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73312/remove-tag-synonym-sequel-sql/73313#73313), even a well-intentioned tag merge can destroy data irrevocably.

*There were probably about [32 questions tagged "sequel"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132053/jeremy-evans#qpage_1-apage_1-qsort_votes-asort_votes) that have all been retagged to "sql".*

We need a mechanism to undo this damage in the rare cases when it occurs again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not necessarily opposed to this, but how does a mis-synonym "destroy data irrevocably"? You check all the posts tagged [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) since the synonym was created and retag the ones that should be [sequel](/questions/tagged/sequel). It's tag *merges* that really screw stuff up, since you now need to check *every* post tagged [sql](/questions/tagged/sql), but that's why merges can only be done by moderators

---

**Edit**: I just read waffles' post:

> what more now there are no questions tagged sequel to be found.

This wouldn't happen from a synonym creation; it sounds like Bill merged the tags. Are you asking for a way to undo tag merges instead of tag synonyms?

Comment: Yes, it was the tag *merge* that caused the real damage.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; not being a mode, I didn't realize they were separate actions. I've clarified the wording.